# Roll up all children pages (1 level down) as a result on a current parent page

Tags: search-results, term-store, content-search-web-part, global-navigation, term-set

I'd like to roll up all children publishing pages (1 level down) on a current page.

All publishing pages from site and its subsites are linked to terms nodes as the global site navigations in a parent-to-children hierarchy structure.

Can Content Search web parts help to archieve this?
If not how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using both the out-of-box Navigation webpart and going through term store navigational terms using Jsom.